# Async functions are unexpectedly blocking each other

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm attempting to run two functions in separate threads that do not block each other. Each thread contains a loop.

Output of below code :

```
%reset -f 

import asyncio
import time

async def run1():

    for i in range(0 , 3) :
        print('run1')
        time.sleep(1)

async def run2():

    for i in range(0 , 3) :
        print('run2')
        time.sleep(2)

async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(
        run1() , run2())

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop) 
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

is :

```
run2
run2
run2
run1
run1
run1
```

But it can also be

```
run1
run1
run1
run2
run2
run2
```

So it seems that once either of thread `run1` or `run2` the thread blocks the other thread of starting until the current run completes.

I'm expecting output similar to :

```
run1
run1
run2
run2
run1
run2
```

How to allow threads `run1` and `run2` to not block each other ?

I'm using Python3.

Comment: Why do you have a blocking call to `time.sleep` in your coroutines? You should be using `asyncio.sleep` https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#id5

Comment: @rdas this is to pause execution of each co-routine.

Comment: It also happens to block the execution of the whole event loop. In general you should not have any blocking call inside a coroutine. It will block the event-loop. In stead what you want to do is `await` on another coroutine so that the event loop knows to switch to some other coroutine  in the meantime.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if your coroutine doesn't `await` anything, it is a coroutine in name only, and it you can be sure that it runs to completion before it passes control to the event loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `time.sleep` to corresponding asyncio version:

```
await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

and the correct result of your code is:

```
run1
run2
run1
run2
run1
run2
```

because `print` happens before `sleep`.